# Fastest way to detect if vector has at least 1 NA?

Tags: r, na

What is the fastest way to detect if a vector has at least 1 `NA` in R?  I've been using:

```
sum( is.na( data ) ) > 0
```

But that requires examining each element, coercion, and the sum function.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As of R 3.1.0 `anyNA()` is the way to do this.  On atomic vectors this will stop after the first NA instead of going through the entire vector as would be the case with `any(is.na())`.  Additionally, this avoids creating an intermediate logical vector with `is.na` that is immediately discarded.  Borrowing Joran's example:

```
x <- y <- runif(1e7)
x[1e4] <- NA
y[1e7] <- NA
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(any(is.na(x)), anyNA(x), any(is.na(y)), anyNA(y), times=10)
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq
#  any(is.na(x))  13444.674  13509.454  21191.9025  13639.3065  13917.592
#       anyNA(x)      6.840     13.187     13.5283     14.1705     14.774
#  any(is.na(y)) 165030.942 168258.159 178954.6499 169966.1440 197591.168
#       anyNA(y)   7193.784   7285.107   7694.1785   7497.9265   7865.064
```

Notice how it is substantially faster even when we modify the last value of the vector; this is in part because of the avoidance of the intermediate logical vector.

Comment: Do you know if `anyNA()` is accessible from R's C API?

Answer (score 76):

I'm thinking:

```
any(is.na(data))
```

should be slightly faster.

Comment: although it still requires iterating through each element.  wondering if there's a first() function or something like that that stops once a condition is met

Comment: Not sure, I wouldn't be surprised if `any()` stops after it finds a FALSE. Any way, the moment where `any(...)` becomes too slow to handle is probably past the moment your RAM runs out.

Comment: There is also the `all()` function that works as expected btw. Might be useful (not for this problem but in general).

Comment: `any` and `all` do stop iterating when they reach a `TRUE` or a `FALSE` respectively; see `checkValues` in http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/logic.c ; the `is.na` still coerces everything though.

Comment: Aaron, the remaining cost is the `is.na(data)` which gets computed first, and for *all* elements of data irrespective of whether an early one is in fact NA.  We do improve on that with the Rcpp sugar version of `is.na()` (which is implemented in C++ for use via Rcpp). See my answer for more.

Answer (score 17):

We mention this in some of our [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) presentations and actually have some benchmarks which show a pretty *large gain* from embedded C++ with Rcpp over the R solution because

- a vectorised R solution still computes *every single element* of the vector expression
- if your goal is to just satisfy `any()`, then you can abort after the first match -- which is what our *Rcpp sugar* (in essence: some C++ template magic to make C++ expressions look more like R expressions, see [this vignette](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) for more) solution does.

So by getting a compiled specialised solution to work, we do indeed get a fast solution. I should add that while I have not compared this to the solutions offered in this SO question here,  I am reasonably confident about the performance.

*Edit* And the Rcpp package contains examples in the directory `sugarPerformance`.  It has an increase of the several thousand of the 'sugar-can-abort-soon' over 'R-computes-full-vector-expression' for `any()`, but I should add that that case does not involve `is.na()` but a simple boolean expression.

Comment: Is there a reason why R's `any` computes every single element, rather than stopping at the first instance?

Comment: R's `any` doesn't know what's inside it; it just evaluates whatever its argument is (all of it) and then applies `any` to it, which does stop at the first `FALSE`, but again, only after evaluating all of its argument.  Dirk's Rcpp sugar version of `any` (as I understand it) does know how to evaluate what's inside of it term by term (at least for some expressions, anyway) so it can check each term for TRUE/FALSE as it's evaluated in turn.

Comment: @Dirk - very cool.  It seems that the most efficient way to do this is with embedded c++...or is that cheating since its not a pure R answer =)  thanks for the link to Rcpp!

Answer (score 8):

One could write a for loop stopping at NA, but the system.time then depends on where the NA is... (if there is none, it takes looooong)

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sample(c(1:5, NA), 100000000, replace = TRUE)

nacount <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:length(x)){
    if(is.na(x[i])) {
      print(TRUE)
      break}
}}

system.time(
  nacount(x)
)
[1] TRUE
       User      System verstrichen 
       0.14        0.04        0.18 

system.time(
  any(is.na(x))
) 
       User      System verstrichen 
       0.28        0.08        0.37 

system.time(
  sum(is.na(x)) > 0
)
       User      System verstrichen 
       0.45        0.07        0.53
```

Comment: great idea to benchmark against the nacount function!  you are right that timing depends on where the first NA is (if any).  I repeated your experiment except I placed a single NA at the end of the long vector.  here are the results:  nacount(x) = 86.14 ,  any(is.na(x)) = .4,   sum(is.na(x)) > 0  = 1.64.   nacount (as expected) is horrible in this case.  what's more interesting is how much better any(...) is than sum(...)>0

Answer (score 6):

Here are some actual times from my (slow) machine for some of the various methods discussed so far:

```
x <- runif(1e7)
x[1e4] <- NA

system.time(sum(is.na(x)) > 0)
> system.time(sum(is.na(x)) > 0)
   user  system elapsed 
  0.065   0.001   0.065 

system.time(any(is.na(x)))  
> system.time(any(is.na(x)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.035   0.000   0.034

system.time(match(NA,x)) 
> system.time(match(NA,x))
  user  system elapsed 
 1.824   0.112   1.918

system.time(NA %in% x) 
> system.time(NA %in% x)
  user  system elapsed 
 1.828   0.115   1.925 

system.time(which(is.na(x) == TRUE))
> system.time(which(is.na(x) == TRUE))
  user  system elapsed 
 0.099   0.029   0.127
```

It's not surprising that `match` and `%in%` are similar, since `%in%` is implemented using `match`.

Comment: thanks for pulling this together.  I think it shows that any(...) is a fantastic, pure R solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
d <- c(1,2,3,NA,5,3)

which(is.na(d) == TRUE, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Comment: I think is.na(d) == TRUE is equivalent to just stating is.na(d)